# How to have this sed command

Tags: sed

can you please help the sed command, that I have to use for my use case..

in the file I currently have this

```
log_location /my/custom/app.log
```

I want this ...

```
log_location "/my/custom/app.log"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to put the second part of the string in quotations?

Comment: for given sample, `echo 'log_location /my/custom/app.log' | sed 's/ \(.*\)/ "\1"/'` will do.. if that doesn't work for all of your use cases, you need to add that detail in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(log_location\) \(\/my\/custom\/app.log\)/\1 "\2"/'
```

this has worked

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(log_location\) \(\/my\/custom\/app.log\)/\1 "\2"/'
```

For terms you want to keep. enclose them in escaped parens `\(` `\)` then refer to those enclosed strings in the order in which they were assigned (first one is `\1`, second is `\2`, etc.)

Comment: Doesn't there need to be an input file?

Comment: sorry may be my question was incomplete i also need find & replace with the sed command

Comment: That's what the answer describes. You will need to be a lot more verbose in what you want to achieve.

Comment: @jcolemang without knowing whether he's using it in a piped expression or directly on a file, I can't give him an exact answer.  I gave the most specific answer I could without guessing as to the unspecified parts because I don't want to cause confusion.

Comment: @DevOpsNewB `sed` does find and replace. You probably have a specific example in mind. If you give us the details of that example, we can give you a more tailored answer.